Is it possible to get a reference of the input control that got an error in the summary?
I need to have a validation summary with a anchor to the input control that have the error so the user can click on it and get into the input without having to "find" it
the input have custom id, I have tried to find a way to get a hold of the ids from the validation summary but I cannot find any built-in way.
I have put a few break point during the life cycle of the process of validating / showing the error(s), only thing I can get so far is the actual property name of the model, not the id of the input.
is my only solution is to refactor the implementation to somehow use the property name of the model?

There is no simple way to tie the validation message with the control that generated it.  You need to write the infrastructure to associate a control with a field in the model so when you click on an message it sets focus to the associated control.  That probably means writing custom versions of all the controls.  A lot of work.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis that is also my conclusion, hoping that someone found something / a solution

Hang on.  Can't components have separate EditContexts?  Can't you just build a collection of components, and send out error info through EventCallbacks?

@Bennyboy1973 how would that help linking html id (markup) to the summary?

Please [edit] your question to include the relevant C# and Blazor code, including the HTML code generated in the browser.
