How to set focus on required validator error message on RadzenTextBox input control
i am working on Redzen controls library with asp.net 7.0 with blazor.
there is issue on set focus on the Redzen required validator on form post. the issue there the required validator popup by showing the validator but the browser window focus not there, i check it on the Redzen library , there is no feature like this to support this with RedzenTextbox control so we need to do custom work there.
Following are code sample
<RadzenTextBox class="form-control" Name="RequestName" @ref="requestNameInput" 
@bind-Value="@SelectedRecord.RequestName" />
<RadzenRequiredValidator @ref="requestNameRequiredValidator" Text="@Localization.GetLabelValue("ThisFieldIsRequired")" 
Component="RequestName" Popup="true" />

Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated.

see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78472061/is-it-possible-to-get-a-reference-of-the-input-control-that-got-an-error-in-the
